# Purge AMQ queue using jolokia api

Tags: curl, activemq-classic, jolokia

Trying to find a way to purge 2 queues in AMQ using the jolokia api and curl.
Found this in the jolokia list:

```
"brokerName=localhost,destinationName=FOO.CommandQueue,destinationType=Queue,type=Broker":
{ ...
              "purge": {
                    "ret": "void",
                    "desc": "Removes all of the messages in the queue.",
                    "args": []
                },
}
```

But unclear how to compose a curl call using this.
Someone who can give some advice?

/J

Answer (score 5):

Well.. it is indeed an old post, but this is the answer:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8161/api/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=[BROKERNAME],destinationType=Queue,destinationName=[QUEUENAME]/purge
```

Perhaps it's useful for anybody.

Answer (score 1):

If you use hawtio [1], then it has a JMX plugin you can use to find the JMX operation to purge. When hawtio shows information about the selected operation, it also shows the jolokia url to use to make the REST call.

You can use hawtio to connect remotely to your ActiveMQ, or install hawtio directly as a web console in the broker - http://sensatic.net/activemq/activemq-and-hawtio.html

- http://hawt.io/

Comment: Hi Claus, I've installed hawtio on my camel/activemq application. I can browse the queues via the camel plugin, or through the JMX tab, but I don't see the purge() operation anywhere. Can you point me in the right direction? I would expect to see it in the 'Operations' tab when I click on an activemq queue in JMX.